# How do I make the buttons stay in their position after they have been clicked and opened a submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 buttons that when clicked they open a submenu, but whenever one is clicked, the other ones move in the page, how can i keep them inline whenever one was clicked?
I've tried changing the positions but then they all become change to be on top of each other, any help will be really appreciated so thank you in advance!

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<button class="menu-trigger btn-1">1</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<button class="menu-trigger btn-1">2</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<button class="menu-trigger btn-1">3</button>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.menu-trigger{
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: lightgray;
}

.menu{
    display: none;
}

.menu.open{
    display:block;
}

.btn-1 {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.btn-1:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

JS

```
 $(function () {
      $(".menu-trigger").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".menu").toggleClass("open"); // Selects only the next one!
        $(this).html($(this).next(".menu").hasClass("open") ? menu-trigger : menu-trigger);
        return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: The ternary operator in you js has the same value for both true and false evaluations?

Comment: Yes, might change it for the button to show something else later but for now just kept it like this for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your HTML markup and add some CSS rules to make work, so I did some changes to your code.

1. you need first to wrap each button with its menu `ul`, wrap them into `ul > li` HTML markup
2. you need to make each `li` that wrap each `<button> <ul>...</ul> </button>` make `display: inline-block;` and `position: relative;`
3. make your `ul.menu` with position `absolute`.

Here you have your code already edited.

```js
$(function () {
      $(".menu-trigger").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".menu").toggleClass("open"); // Selects only the next one!
        $(this).html($(this).next(".menu").hasClass("open") ? menu-trigger : menu-trigger);
        return false;
      });
    });
```

```css
.menu-trigger{
    padding: 10px 25px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    color: lightgray;
}

.menu-container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-container > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.menu.open{
    display:block;
}

.btn-1 {
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.btn-1:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='menu-container'>
<li>
  <button class="menu-trigger btn-1">1</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <button class="menu-trigger btn-1">2</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <button class="menu-trigger btn-1">3</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I hope you find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

CSS:

```
  .menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    float:left;
    display: none;
   }

.btn-1 {
   float: left;
   border: 2px solid yellow;
 }
```

and in your code:

```
$(function () {
  $(".menu-trigger").click(function () {
      $(".menu").hide();
    $(this).next(".menu").toggleClass("open"); // Selects only the next one!
    $(this).next(".menu").show();
    $(this).html($(this).next(".menu").hasClass("open") ? menu-trigger : menu-trigger);
  });
});
```